# Sparks out out of my electrical metal flex conduit

Tags: electrical

I recently moved a switch from the wall to the side of cabinet and running the wires with some flex conduit (12/3).

After everything was connected, I moved the cabinets in to place and in the act of doing so, I think the metal conduit flexed a bit and I saw sparks from the wall box with the utility plate and the 1/2 inch knock out.

At the time, the conduit fitting / lock thing into the box was like the one on the box on the side of the cabinet, the kind with 2 screws and plate that presses on the flex conduit.

My thinking was that I over tightened it and it caused the sparks. 
When the sparks occurred, the breaker didn't flip, so I went and manually turned it off. I removed the plate and inspected the wires and saw burn marks.
I removed the damaged length of wire and re-installed, this time with a different fitting. (Which I think is now too big and can't be replaced)

Everything else looked good, all wire nuts, box contexts etc.

Did I do anything wrong, should I be OK if I don't over tightened the connector?
Is there currently any risk?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In which of these two boxes did you observe sparks? Can you take a picture showing the inside of the boxes?

Comment: The sparks came from the one in the back - and to be fair, I think they were from the conduit connection. The plate was already on so I don't think I would have seen a spark in the box. I'm not there anymore (it's at my parent's house) - I'll take a picture in a couple days. (In the mean time, the breaker is off)

Comment: That looks more like an armored cable whip than flexible conduit.  If the wires are pre-installed, that is MC not conduit.  The cable clamps also look a little odd, like they are for Romex not MC.  Did you put the plastic guard pieces on the cut edge of the MC or conduit to protect the wires from being cut by it?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a weak ground fault somewhere else on this circuit that's not tripping the breaker, but causing current to flow through the EGC system and thus through the conduit?

Comment: @Harper - I honestly don't know what I have. I just trusted the big box store person. Probably not the best call there. I did not see any plastic pieces.

Comment: I think the safest thing for me to do is to get an appliance whip, this way, no crimping or tighething or whatever - the problem is they're all 6 feet --- is that an issue - can I coil the excess length?

Comment: Sure, coiling the excess length is fine.  Or you could use real flexible metal conduit and individual wires, but buy it at a real electrical supply so they will sell you the correct clamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the answer, but many times when those with less knowledge connect MC to a box they may have made a common mistake. First they don't install an anti-short bushing (red devil) and second even if they did they will attach the squeeze connector too tight, thus cutting the armored cable into a conductor. That and looking for any exposed wire coming out of a wirenut splice would be the first place I would look.

Keep the breaker off, stay safe and good luck.